# Can anyone tell me why it wont recognize role.Name in my EditRole method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, identity

I create a Name field within RoleManager  and further down the class i try to call this field but it wont recognize it. it recognizes it in my view so im not sure whats happening. i had been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGIT8P29jf4

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole(CreateRoleViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                IdentityRole identityRole = new IdentityRole
                {
                    Name = model.RoleName
                };
                IdentityResult result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(identityRole);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ListRoles", "Administration");
                }

                foreach(IdentityError error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
                }
            }




            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ListRoles()
        {
            var roles = roleManager.Roles;
            return View(roles);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EditRole(string id)
        {
            var role = roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

            if (role == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Role with Id = {id} cannot be found";
            }

            var model = new EditRoleViewModel
            {
                Id = role.Id,
                RoleName = role.Name
            };

            foreach (var user in userManager.Users)
            {
                if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
                {

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think roleManager.FindByIdAsync would be returning a Task<IdentityRole> since it's an async method. Try going `await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);` since EditRole is async. Let us know if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that roleManager.FindByIdAsync was returning a Task. They needed to await to function call.